# Recursive xgettext?

Tags: php, gettext, xgettext

How can I compile a `.po` file using xgettext with PHP files with a single command recursively?

My PHP files exist in a hierarchy, and the straight `xgettext` command doesn't seem to dig down recursively.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it:

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext
```

I was trying to use `-exec` before, but that would only run one file at a time. This runs them on the bunch.

Yay Google!

Comment: well it's not working for me, but you showed me a way for possibility otherwise would be accepted and live with it as if there is no better way that this

Comment: Hi, Nice work, but becarefull to add -j at end of the command, unless it wont works

Comment: This is wrong, because if there are too many files to fit on one commandline, xargs will run xgettext multiple times, causing the earlier invocations to be clobbered.  Just adding -j isn't right, either, since you need to delete the file first or you'll join with the old data.

Comment: And adding -j when a file *doesn't* exist throws an error.  xgettext isn't very mature...

Comment: See also answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12692493/133408 with `--files-from` option if many files are parsed

Comment: @GlennMaynard I am trying to extract gettexted labels from my project which has more than 3,000 .php files and yes some files are ignored. How can I get ALL the gettexted labels? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ivantxo Please post your question as a question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For WINDOWS command line a simpe solution is:

```
 @echo off
echo Generating file list..
dir html\wp-content\themes\wpt\*.php /L /B /S > %TEMP%\listfile.txt
echo Generating .POT file...
xgettext -k_e -k__ --from-code utf-8  -o html\wp-content\themes\wpt\lang\wpt.pot -L PHP --no-wrap -D html\wp-content\themes\wpt -f %TEMP%\listfile.txt
echo Done.
del %TEMP%\listfile.txt
```

Comment: Some warning just in case: `pygettext.py` does not support the option `-f`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot achieve this with one single command.  The xgettext option `--files-from` is your friend.

```
find . -name '*.php' >POTFILES
xgettext --files-from=POTFILES
```

If you are positive that you do not have too many source files you can also use `find` with `xargs`:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 xgettext
```

However, if you have too many source files, `xargs` will invoke `xgettext` multiple times so that the maximum command-line length of your platform is not exceeded.  In order to protect yourself against that case you have to use the xgettext option `-j`, `--join-existing`, remove the stale messages file first, and start with an empty one so that xgettext does not bail out:

```
rm -f messages.po
echo >messages.po
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 xgettext --join-existing
```

Compare that with the simple solution given first with the list of source files in `POTFILES`!

Using `find` with `--exec` is very inefficient because it will invoke `xgettext -j` once for every source file to search for translatable strings.  In the particular case of `xgettext -j` it is even more inefficient because xgettext has to read the evergrowing existing output file `messages.po` with every invocation (that is with every input source file).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Windows. At first, install gettext and find from the GnuWin32 tools collection.

- http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm
- gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm

You can run the following command afterwards:

```
find /source/directory -iname "*.php" -exec xgettext -j -o /output/directory/messages.pot {} ;
```

The output file has to exist prior to running the command, so the new definitions can be merged with it.

Comment: Perhaps installing and using Cygwin? I know it's not a native solution, but should get you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found for recursive search on Mac:

```
xgettext -o translations/messages.pot --keyword=gettext `find . -name "*.php"`
```

Generates entries for all uses of method gettext in files whose extension is php, including subfolders and inserts them in translations/messages.pot .

Comment: Leave a little descriptive text