# How to use xgettext how to parse directory?

Tags: php, gettext

in manual there are a option -D for parse directory but when i do `xgettext -D /home/cawa/www/zf2/' i have en error the input file is missing?

Comment: because i need to do it automated whet i using phing? with po edit it works great but i need to do it with command line

Comment: i can parse files in 1 directory but how can i scan the subdirectory??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was

```
find /home/cawa/www/deploy/module/Nav/ -type f \( -name '*.php' -or -name '*.phtml' \)  -print > list
xgettext --files-from=list --language=PHP -j messages.po
```

Comment: `--files-from` option is crucial for larger projects, thank you

Answer (score 7):

You could use this cmd to recursively get all files in a directory.

```
find . -iname "*.py" | xargs xgettext --from-code utf-8 -o messages.pot
```