# how to xgettext with all the file including subdirectories files?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

how to xgettext with all the file including subdirectories files?
I tried to

```
xgettext -n *.php
```

but it only generates *.po files in current directory without child directories' files.
any option needed to recursively do the command?

Comment: Maybe is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864233/recusive-xgettext ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
find . -name "*.php" >POTFILES
xgettext -n --files-from=POTFILES
```