# how to extract string from all c files in a folder using gettext

Tags: localization, xgettext

I'm trying to localize a 'C' project but I have no idea how to extract Strings by xgettext . And project has so many C files so extracting one by one is not feasible. S is it possible to extract strings from all files once. or there is any other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe all of your *.c files to the xgettext program using `xargs` assuming you're on Linux/Mac, e.g:

```
~$ find MyFolder -name "*.c \
   | xargs xgettext --keyword=_ --language=C --output=messages.pot -
```

Be sure to pass `-` as the last parameter so it reads all files from stdin. Also you'll want to replace my simple `keyword=_` example with the correct C function names.

Comment: In my case I did not need the trailing `-`

Answer (score 0):

From similar [question in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864233/recursive-xgettext), it is easy to know:

```sh
find . -iname "*.c" | xargs xgettext
```